# No reconoce el color de un enlace <a> dentro de <p> al hacer :hover fuera de <a>

Tags: hover

Estoy intentando lograr que al pasar el ratón por encima con :hover el color del texto dentro de

como enlace  tenga un color determinado pero por mas pruebas que hago siempre sale en blanco tanto el fondo como el texto y solo si me posiciono dentro del texto sale en color azul.

```
 <!-- Introduction -->
            <section id="inicio">
                <article class="header">                        
                    <h1><span>Título</span><br>
                        Más contenido del título <br> 
                        Última frase del título.
                    </h1>               
                    <p><a href="contacto" title="Contácteme" class="boton-contactar"> Contácteme</a></p>                
                </article>              
            </section>

:root {
--azul-marino-oscuro: #354355;
}

#inicio p{
    background: var(--azul-marino-oscuro);
    color: white;       
    margin-top: 1rem;   
    border-radius:10px; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;  
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 36%; 
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: all 400ms ease; 
}

#inicio p:hover{    
    background-color: white;
    color: var(--azul-marino-oscuro) !important;
    cursor: pointer;        
}

#inicio p > a.boton-contactar:hover{    
    color: var(--azul-marino-oscuro) !important;    
}
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que salga dicho color --azul-marino-oscuro al pasar el ratón en :hover sobre el blanco de

sin tocar ? Es decir que incluya todo el fondo en el :hover y no solo el texto que hay en  para reconocer el nuevo color.

Comment: No deberías usar important, rompe la especificidad y la cascada, es una mala práctica

Comment: Al no encontrar el error los puse por si colaban pero normalmente no los uso. Gracias BetaM por la recomendación

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!-- Introduction -->
            <section id="inicio">
                <article class="header">                        
                    <h1><span>Título</span><br>
                        Más contenido del título <br> 
                        Última frase del título.
                    </h1>               
                    <p>
                        <a href="contacto" 
                            title="Contácteme" 
                            class="boton-contactar">  
                            Contácteme
                        </a>
                    </p>                
                </article>              
            </section>
<style>
:root {
--azul-marino-oscuro: #354355;
}

#inicio p{
    background: var(--azul-marino-oscuro);
    color: white;       
    margin-top: 1rem;   
    border-radius:10px; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;  
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 36%; 
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: all 400ms ease; 
}

#inicio p:hover{    
    background-color: white;
    color: var(--azul-marino-oscuro) !important;
    cursor: pointer;        
}

#inicio p:hover > a.boton-contactar{    
    color: var(--azul-marino-oscuro) !important;    
}
</style>
```

Simplemente he cambiado el elemento al que aplicas el hover, lo aplicabas al elemento `a` que es el afectado por el cambio pero no es el que intentas que lo active, entonces solo hay que cambiar:

```
#inicio p > a.boton-contactar:hover
```

por

```
#inicio p:hover > a.boton-contactar
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
   p > a.colorx{    
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;        
    }

    p:hover > a.colorx{    
        color: red;    
    }
```

```html
<p><a href="#" class="colorx">Cambia con el hover</a></p>
```

Comment: Si explicaras tu código sería aún mejor y mas fácil de entenderlo